# Concurrent progam in C(Concurrent or Sequential?)

Tags: c, concurrency, system-calls

Would this code be considered concurrent or sequential? I think it is concurrent because there a for-loop and it creates processes and for each process there a child,parent, etc... so they all run in parallel. Would this be right?

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ATTRIBUTES //
    int freq[argc-1], ipc[argc][2], nbytes, i;// freq of words, pipes, counters
    ssize_t errorfi;
    char  readbuffer[9999];
    char** k = malloc(50);
    char** op = malloc(50);


    if(argc == ONE) { // there are no files given, throw error and close
      fprintf(stderr, "There are no files found from %s\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
    }

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) // creates pipes for ipc
       pipe(ipc[i]);

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) { // reads input after position 0(a.out)

        pid_t pid = fork(); // creates process

        if( pid < 0 ) {       // bad fork process: error
          perror("bad fork");
          exit(0);
        }
        else if(pid > 0) {   //parent process

          close(ipc[i][1]);
          wait(NULL);
          nbytes = read(ipc[i][0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));

          if(nbytes > 0)
          printf("%s\n", readbuffer);
        }
        else if(pid == 0) {  // child process

           close(ipc[i][0]);

           k = inputReader(argv[i]); // finds filename,w1,w2,w3,uniqueWords

           char info[50];

           strcat(info, k[0]);
           strcat(info, " ");
           strcat(info, k[1]);
           strcat(info, " ");
           strcat(info, k[2]);
           strcat(info, " ");
           strcat(info, k[3]);
           strcat(info, " ");
           strcat(info, k[4]);

           int uniqueWordint = atoi(k[4]);
           freq[i-1] = uniqueWordint; // freq of all uniqueWords

           errorfi = write(ipc[i][1], info, strlen(info)+1); // writes info to pipe i

           if (errorfi < 0 ) {

              fprintf(stderr, "error found when writing in pipe errofi: %d\n", errorfi);
              exit(0);
           }

      exit(0); // close process
     }// closes child process
   } // closes for-loop for each process
     return(0); // close main 
 } // closes main
```

Comment: How do you think, how many child processes can exist simultaneously in this program?

Comment: Well each file it reads a process is created

Comment: So depending on the input if 3 files then 3 processes?

Comment: Which means it is concurrent? I made this code im just curious because i am not sure myself since i am new to concurrency

Comment: My point is that they will not be executed *simultaneously*. In your code, the parent creates a child process 0, then waits for its termination, then creates a child process 1, waits until it's done, creates child process 2, waits, exits. Well, technically, this program runs two processes (parent and child) at some points, so it can be called 'concurrent'. But it feels more like sequential to me.

Comment: How can i change it to be more concurrent? Maybe another for-loop or use wait() somewhere else?

Comment: The parent should first spawn all child processes (so all children could run *concurrently*), and only then wait() for them and collect their results. This means you need to move wait()&read() part outside the spawning for-loop.

Comment: So then wait() and read should be outside this for-loop? Meaning there is only one for-loop used?  Also, what do you mean as in "spawn all child processes" because each process has a child and parent... so each process will have a different parent?

Comment: I believe you'll need another for-loop (or two) for waits&reads. The parent process will have several children, and all the child processes will have the same parent.